# Berkeley DB corrupted without transactions?

Tags: transactions, berkeley-db

Is it true, that if a Berkeley DB is opened for writing (and is written) by several concurrent processes without transactions, the DB may be corrupted?

Comment: You might want to show some research effort in the question yourself - what is the basis of your doubts for the db corruption?

Answer (score 0):

We need locking. (Transactions are no strictly necessary however.) See http://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/help/BerkeleyDB/ref/debug/common.html in the documentation:

**Symptom:**
Running multiple threads or processes, and the database appears to be getting corrupted.

**Possible Cause:**
Locking is not enabled.

**Fix:**
Make sure that you are acquiring locks in your access methods. You must specify DB_INIT_LOCK to your DB_ENV->open call and then pass that environment to DB->open.